# PHP7 - Connect to sybase database

Tags: php, apache, sybase, php-7

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-connect.php is removed as from PHP7.

So now I am gettings this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect()
```

How am I supposed to connect to sybase now with PHP7?

Comment: What is your operation system? You must find alternative module, for example in Ubuntu you got https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/php7.0-sybase

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
I've installed php7.0-sybase but the sybase_connect function is not working.

Comment: It can't be done with `sybase_connect`. I'm going to create a full answer in a while.

Comment: make sure that you have activated module after installation, `phpenmod php7.0-sybase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu 16.04, so after installation of [php7.0-sybase](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/php7.0-sybase) package in your system, you are able to connect with Sybase database using [pdo_dblib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

> Example #1 PDO_DBLIB DSN examples
>
> sybase:host=localhost;dbname=testdb

Following general [PDO reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), you create connection like this

```
$databaseHandler = new PDO('sybase:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', $user, $pass);
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04: `$dbh=new PDO('dblib:host=localhost:5000;dbname=testdb',$user,$pass);`