# Call to undefined function sybase_connect() - Cenos 7 and php 7.2.12

Tags: centos7, sybase, php-7.2

I have theses errors in php v7.2.12 in Centos 7.

Before that my website are running on

OS FreeBSD 10.1, Apache 5.4.23 , PHP 5.4.23, TDS 0.64 and I try to migrate my webiste to

Centos7, Apache 5.4.16, PHP 7.2.12, TDS 0.95.81 and after I install everything needed and try to run, these error show on my screen.

How can I resolve following errors?

> Warning: Use of undefined constant SYBASE - assumed 'SYBASE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/lib/dbHead.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect() in /var/www/html/lib/dbHead.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/auth.php(38): getSybaseConnection('friana', 'fjgzvlpbgg', 'DEMO_3', '', false) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/lib/dbHead.php on line 40

Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890610/php7-connect-to-sybase-database

Comment: @rohitthomas Thanks for the response. 
I Already change my code and try to run  again. and my screen show this error 
Error!: could not find driver

Comment: What command did you run  for which you got the error ??

Comment: <?php

try {

    $user='';
    $pass='';
    $dbh = new PDO('sybase:host=192.**.***.***;dbname=""', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from caregiver_code_view') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}


?>

And I already install this driver php72u-pdo-7.2.12

Comment: did you add  php7.0-sybase  package?

Comment: What do you mean to add? as I mention early I already install the Php72u-pdo-7.2.12 which is the compatible package for php7.2.12. Thanks @rohitthomas

Comment: give this a try `Driver issue` related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813574/pdo-returning-error-could-not-find-driver-with-a-known-working-dsn

Comment: Good Day @rohitthomas, I figureout what drivers could not find which is the sybase itself. So, I change my code to ` $dbh = new PDO('dblib:host=192.**.***.***;dbname=""', $user, $pass); `  then after I run the next error occurred **Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)**. As of now I am searching for the solution to figure out what's cause of this error. Thanks Rohit I really apprecaite you.